# reliable USB wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, usb

I am aware that questions that are considered as subjective, will not be allowed on this forum.  But, the following question i have is very specific, because of the way i constructed this question (to avoid being subjective), and the answer could be useful to many like me, who are moving to Ubuntu 14.04, but stuck at the networking step.   I have searched long and hard on the net, to find an answer. But after many hours spent, i could not find anything. Posting this question in Ubuntu forum, did not produce any answer either. So, i created this account here, as a final resort. I hope the admins will not close this thread.

I am newbie to Ubuntu & Linux. I want to setup my Windows 7 PC for Ubuntu. This machine will run both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 (booted from a USB drive), when i finally set it up. During my preparation, i noticed that there are lot of questions on the net about USB wireless adapters not working with Ubuntu. I want to buy a wireless USB adapter that will

1. be compatible and has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04.
2. not only compatible, but more importantly, will work reliably without
   dropping connection everyday.
3. will run in N300 or N150 (second
   choice) protocol.
4. currently my other machines are on WPA2-PSK (AES
   encryption). So i would like the same in this new USB stick.
5. will also
   work reliably when the machine boots in Windows 7 mode.

I tend to run this machine continuously; so i need a wireless USB stick that will run for atleast a few days , without disconnections. If you have come across a USB for 14.04, that meets all OR some of the above criteria, please let me know. I have to buy this USB (hopefully from local Frys store) as soon as possible. I am using a NetGear (N 300 speed) router, and so it would be nice if i can find a Netgear USB wireless adapter. From past experience i know that it would be a safer bet, when the router and desktop receiver are paired from the same company. So, i am leaning towards NetGear, but am not tied to the brand, if i can find a reliable USB dongle that works on both Windows and Ubuntu 14.04.

Looking forward to preparing my Ubuntu bootable USB drive tomorrow. 
Thanks for any leads.

Comment: What should this wireless usb stick do? Connect to WiFi? Connect to blueootoh accesories?

Comment: This question still risks being closed as **off topic** because it's asking for a [shopping recommendation](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) so I recommend you ask on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=326) instead.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of netgear. I have one device not in use, but will test it on ubuntu 14.04 when updgrading my laptop.

Here are the amazon specs:
http://www.amazon.de/Netgear-Dual-Band-Adapter-Paneurope/dp/B002RLC7WO/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1404911312&sr=8-7&keywords=wifi+netgear+usb

Have fun
Gerrit

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing wifi device driver containing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

then reboot and connect the device.

Comment: I am planning on a USB boot drive, for initial evaluation of the system, before i install Ubuntu.  Are these packages part of the standard Ubuntu USB boot system ?  Or, do i need to download them seperately and put it somewhere in the USB boot stick that i will prepare for Ubuntu ? Thanks for your reply.